# How can I confirm my server is running on a 1 Gbit network interface?

Tags: windows-server-2008

I am not a network administrator by any means but need to confirm something for an automation project. I need to verify by screenshot whether my server is running on 1 Gbit network interface. How can I confirm that this feature exists on my Windows 2008 Server?

Comment: Just so I'm aware, why am I getting downvoted here?

Comment: Probably due to the "does not show any research effort" criterion. (Note that I didn't downvote your question. I was inclined to do so but reckoned -4 was enough. Note also that downvoting applies to the question, not to your person.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In powershell type

**For Server 2012:**

```
Get-NetAdapter
```

You will receive something like this:

```
Name                      InterfaceDescription                    ifIndex Status       MacAddress             LinkSpeed
Ethernet0                 vmxnet3 Ethernet Adapter                     12 Up           00-0C-xx-xx-xx-xx        10 Gbps
```

**For earlier versions:**

```
Get-WMIObject Win32_NetworkAdapter
```

bluemulch points out that it is probably better to do

```
Get-WMIObject Win32_NetworkAdapter | Format-Table
```

Comment: Apparently that command requires 2012 Server.

Comment: @bluemunch made an edit

Comment: Thanks. That worked. I actually used ``Get-WMIObject Win32_NetWorkAdapter | format-table`` for display purposes.

Comment: I can genuinely taste the salt lol. From a non-network admin I think this is a fairly useful question.

Comment: I didn't downvote you, but on the other hand I found this answer as top result in google. ;)

Comment: Lol I guess negative press is good press!

Answer (score 2):

1. Open the control panel
2. Go to `Network and Sharing Center`
3. Go to `Network adapters`
4. Double click on the adapter

A dialog opens, looking similar to this:

[image]

The network speed is displayed there.

Comment: Thanks. This is also a great solution and I can confirm it works. Definitely more visual.